# Incentive for offering discounted services to NPO/Charity/501(c)(3)?

Tags: tax-law, non-profit, charity

**Backstory:**

I am exploring options for a business that offers Software, Platform and Infrastructure as-a-service (SAAS, IAAS and PAAS) and Insurance-Billing services to **Ambulance companies**, **Fire Departments**, **Schools**, and other **Charitable** and **Not-for-profit** organizations.

These organizations tend to have strict budgets and often encounter financial impasses that directly affect their ability to maintain subscriptions and use productivity software and services that ultimately impact their businesses and their communities.

We would like to offer discounts to these organizations, but our profit margin is already quite low, and we would essentially be breaking even or paying clients to use our products and services.

**Question:**

Can such discounts be considered tax-deductible charitable donations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under U.S. federal tax law: In general, a *discount* on a service provided to a charity is not tax-deductible.  There is no deduction for "opportunity cost."

So, for example, if you bill professionally at $100/hour, but you offer service to a qualified charity at $25/hour, you do not get to deduct $75/hour of your time.  But you *can* generally deduct the value of things that you pay for and give to the charity, like travel costs you incur specifically to serve the charity.  So if you really are providing SaaS to a qualified charity *at a loss* then the difference between your cost and what you charge the charity could be deducted as a contribution for tax purposes.

The rules covering tax consequences of charitable contributions are in [IRS Publication 526](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p526.pdf).

And if you find that easy enough, you can dive into [26 U.S.C §170](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/170) ... and the IRS's [occasional attempts to explain its interpretation of that law with respect to *in-kind* contributions](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-tege/eotopice94.pdf).  Suffice it to say that if you aren't comfortable arguing for your interpretation of the rules then you should defer to a qualified attorney or accountant who is.

Comment: When you say "charity", does that apply to NPO's and 501(c)(3) as well?
For example - could we deduct our operating costs for a Community College or 501(c)(3), or would that apply only to actual Charities?

Comment: @TaterJuice – The technical term you want for "charity" is "qualified organization."  That includes any 501(c)(3), churches, most government entities – the IRS determines who is qualified.  You can check whether an organization is qualified at https://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/exempt-organizations-select-check

Comment: What if, instead of giving a 25% discount to a charity, I charged them full rate and then donated 25% of what they paid me, back to them?

Comment: @moonman239 interesting idea!

Comment: @feetwet: Would it work, or is tax law wise to such a trick?

Comment: @moonman239 I don't know -- it's worth asking as a separate question.  IRS code has plenty of disallowances for arrangements that effectively do things they don't want to allow, but there are also plenty of valid "tax optimizations" that are *not* specifically disallowed.

Comment: @moonman239 actually it's almost certainly allowed because there is no tax benefit to doing that: The maximum tax benefit is to reduce your taxable income dollar-for-dollar on whatever you return/"donate" back to the charity.  But this is true of any discount you offer to any customer: You don't pay taxes on money you don't earn!